# How to store replacement patterns in a field and get them to be replaced in a view?

Tags: views, entities

I have two product types: Online Store and Product. The Online Store content type contains information such as name, URL, etc along with a Product URL template text field. What I mean by that is the link to the Products of the store all using the same URL except for the product id number. For example, I store a product link template to the website in a field on the Online Store content type like this:
"http://www.onlinestorename.com/items/product.php?id=[field_product_id_value]"

For Products content type, I have an entity reference field to a specific Online Store. I also have a product ID field (field_product_id_value).

When I create a table based view of Products in Drupal 7, I use entity reference so that I can also display the name of the Online Store, the URL, and the product link template. For each product row, I want to use the product link template pulled from the Online Store and replace the [field_product_id_value] with the product ID.

My problem is that I can't figure out a method to get the [field_product_id_value] replacement pattern to be replaced in product link template that is being pulled from the Online Store content type.

Basically, I am creating the link to the products on the fly instead of storing the links in the Product content type. Storing the product link in a field takes up a lot of database space hence the reason to create the link on the fly and have the pages cached.

Any thoughts?